Complex limits of integration, what are they exactly?
I am trying to solve:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + it + t^2} \cdot (i+2t) \, dt
$$
the result should be log$(2+i)$. One may get the result by  expressing the integrand in terms of its real and imaginary components, then one has:
$$
\frac{1}{1 + it + t^2} \cdot (i+2t) \ =\frac{3t + 2t^3}{t^4 + 3t^2 + 1} + \frac{(-t^2 + 1)i}{t^4 + 3t^2 + 1}
$$
So we can proceed by using integration in the $\mathbb{R}$eal sense.
My concern comes from the fact that, if I tried to to the following substitution
$$u=1+it+t^2
\text{ with } (i+2t)dt=du$$
then my new limits of integration would be complex numbers, but I don't know what to think of them in the most rigurous sense of what a complex integral is. Since the definitions I have seen for contour integration involve real limits of integration, I don't know how to proceed here...
Is this reasonable? How is the theory constructed to deal with these cases? How does one make sense of integrals with bounds of integration being complex numbers?

It is typical for a contour integral of a reasonably well behaved complex function to be path independent, just like conservative vector fields in Physics  . In particular, the function $f(z)=\frac 1z$ has no pole on your contour, and no branch cuts separating $z=1$ from $z = 2 + i$

Did you realize that the indefinite integral is $\ln(1+it+t^2)$?

You will need to clarify your question further for more clear answers, but my rough understanding is that you are asking how does one make sense of integrals with bounds of integration being complex numbers, and the answer is the same way you deal with multi-variable line integrals. You don’t just need the endpoints, but also a parameterization of the path being traversed, be it a line, parabola, or otherwise.
Here, $u = 1 + i t + t^2$ doesn’t just provide bounds of integration, but also a parameterization of the path being traversed along when doing the line integral.

Thanks, I am definitely asking that :)

Of course, that's for non-analytic functions. If the function were analytic, the integral would be path-independent. Since the OP's function has poles, the integral will depend on which "side" of the poles they go around.

I think that you could make the problem simpler writing
$$\frac{i+2t}{1 + it + t^2}=\frac{i+2t}{(t-a)(t-b)} \quad \text{with}\quad (a,b)=-\frac{1}{2} i \left(1\pm\sqrt{5}\right)$$  and then partial fractions
$$\frac{i+2t}{(t-a)(t-b)}=\frac 1{a-b}\Bigg( \frac{2 a+i}{t-a}- \frac{2 b+i}{t-b} \Bigg)$$ which give for the definite integral
$$\frac 1{a-b}\Bigg((2 a+i) \log \left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)-(2 b+i) \log \left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\Bigg)$$
Replace $(a,b)$ by their values to get the result.
